# Get URL ID in react

Tags: reactjs

Hey I have a question how can we catch the `id` from `url`

```
 onProductClick = item => {
    this.props.history.push(`/product/${item.id}`);
  };
```

How can we assign this coming `id` from `url` to variable in react

This is the place i've planned to catch the id valuer

```
class ProductView extends React.Component {
 componentDidMount() {
let someVar = this.props.location.pathname.split('/').pop()
console.log('router val ', someVar);}
```

Comment: Please clarify, what is the id you're trying to push and where it needs to come from?.. What do you mean by URL ID?

Comment: @S.Haviv  Its like this  http://localhost:3000/product/12 , In product page how can i catch the id(12)

Comment: It seems like you are using react-router, i think you should mention that in your question. So is id a query or path parameter? And exaxctly what is your question. Would you like to read the item.id again some other place in your code?

Comment: I can't see it, it's a dev server for you locally only.

Comment: @the_cheff Its like this localhost:3000/product/12 , In product page how can i catch the id(12)

Comment: You could just parse the url string, something like this `let someVar = this.props.location.pathname.split('/').pop()`

Comment: @S.Haviv its in my local server . So Im asking something simple .. for and example look at below url 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55157279 this url end has 55157279 . so if someone need to assign this 5515727 to variable how can we do that in react

Comment: @the_cheff Its getting error (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined)

Comment: are you open to using a router library? If yes, do look at [reach-router](https://reach.tech/router) parsing params from URLs can work for simple cases, but in the long term, having declarative routing will help eliminate your woes

Comment: Well you are not showing your entire code (the code where you actually read the variable in your question) so it is a bit hard to tell what that component has access to. So I was expecting that the component which does this is wrapped in withRouter, such that it has this.props.location. It sounds like this is not true. Please update your question with the code where you actually try to read the value, instead of the code where you write it.

Comment: @the_cheff i update the code

Comment: When you use ProductView you need to wrap it in withRouter in order to get location as a prop. The usual way to do this is by exporting the class like this `export default withRouter(ProductView)` Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @the_cheff You can find project file here https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1KZ6gkxkst0eeZlB1hb33yhoJhMMeDeuZ?usp=sharing can u look and tell me exactly wts the issue

Comment: Are you using react-router? It seems like it, since you use history.push, but you never said anywhere that you are? If yes: You can do exactly what i said in my previous comment in the file you send. In the top of your file import withRouter like `import { withRouter } from "react-router"` in the bottom of your file export it like this `export default withRouter(ProductView)` If you are NOT using react router you can simply use `let someVar = window.location.href.split('/').pop()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems as if you are using react-router, the route in which you want to fetch the id should be added while declaring routes like this. > path="/product/:id" This should be done where you are mentioning your routes and routing a particular component.

Inside the routed component who will find the id in the props mostly with this value. this.props.match.params.id

This may differ depending upon the routing technique but you can log your props and fetch the value with the proper key.